# How to retrieve the list of exceptions of a function or a method

Tags: python, exception

How can I have a clean list of exceptions that a standard function/method can raise ? Without that, how can I anticipate the behavior of a function ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to get a full list of exception a function can raise. You can look in the documentation, some functions list the exceptions they raise.

Comment: This. The expected behaviour is in the documentation. Everything else (including undocumented exceptions) is a bug or a deficit in the documentation, but cannot be anticipated because Python doesn't really lend it to formal proofs ;) Or, more realistically, to static analysis (which still only gets a portion of bugs even in very static languages).